# Rally API date filter doesn't work

Tags: rally

I am trying to filter the data based on date but it fetch all

The format of  "FlowStateChangedDate": "2018-07-18T01:00:15.301Z",

> https://host.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query
>   =**((FlowStateChangedDate >= 2018-06-01 ) AND  (FlowStateChangedDate <= 2018-06-02) )**&fetch=FormattedID&start=1&pagesize=2000

Answer (score 0):

The url should be encoded.Else at least

```
>= should be %3E%3D
<= should be %3C%3D
```